# Lookup table in Latex

Tags: latex, lookup-tables, control-structure

I have a bunch of automatically generated LaTeX code with hypertargets of the form "functionname_2093840289fad1337", i.e the name of a function with a hash appended. I would like to refer to those functions from the rest of the document by only referring to the function name which I know is unique. I would like a lookup function something like this:

```
\hyperdyperlink{functionname}
```

that emits

```
\hyperlink{functionname_2093840289fad1337}{functionname}
```

Note that I can't calculate the hash but I'm prepared to write a table that maps each functionname to functionname+hash. What's the best way to write this kind of function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work?

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\hashlink[2]{%
    \@namedef{hashlink-#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand\hyperdyperlink[1]{%
    \hyperlink
    {#1_\@nameuse{hashlink-#1}}
    {#1}%
}
\hashlink{functionname}{2093840289fad1337}
\hyperdyperlink{functionname}
\makeatother
```

(Untested.)

---

**Later:** To branch the code depending if you've defined the link target, you can write something like

```latex
\newcommand\hyperdyperlink[1]{%
    \@ifundefined{hashlink-#1}{%
    [whatever else you want to do]
    }{%
    \hyperlink{#1_\@nameuse{hashlink-#1}}{#1}%
    }%
}
```

(**Update:** oops; that was pretty broken as first posted, sorry. Now fixed, I hope.)

Comment: Only problem I've found is that I get a really hairy error if I haven't defined the link target yet. Is it possible to see if a name exist and do something different (like linking to {} or similar?)

Answer (score 5):

Since the function names are unique, could you not define the hyperlink targets without the hash appended?

Alternatively, you could create a new LaTeX macro for each function. The code that generates the LaTeX code could do this by outputting code like this:

```
\newcommand{\linkFoo}{\hyperlink{foo_2093840289fad1337}{foo}}
\newcommand{\linkBar}{\hyperlink{bar_4323812312asf1342}{bar}}
```

Then use `\linkFoo` and friends in your hand-written part.

You could also implement a proper lookup table with TeX macros if you really wanted -- see [this thread for an example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/303cf2db13540bce/2cde87e4abfbb81f) -- but this solution is quite easy and simpler to understand (IMHO).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The hashes represents the parameter lists and return types but we work with C symbols only which doesn't support overloading of function names.

Comment: @Will: ah, I guess you mean to point out that \ifcase is only for integer cases... that makes sense now that I think of it with the \today macro :-)

Comment: I've removed the \ifcase example since it didn't make much sense.

Comment: You also wouldn't have wanted to count from zero all the way up to 2093840289fad1337 number of \or's :)